# How to select all elements based on alternative attributes? [BeautifulSoup]

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to select all html-tags that has class attribute if the class name is in list **OR** has a style attribute with the specified value.

I tried to solve my problem step by step and I got this:

```
selected_by_class = soup.find_all(class_=['basic_class', 'other_class'])
selected_by_style = soup.find_all(style='text-align:left')
```

As you can see, I'm getting all the data in two steps, but the sequence is lost, because I do two independent `find_all()` requests.

How to do it simultaneously with a single `find_all()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using CSS Selectors. To use multiple Selectors, separate them with a comma `,`.

To use a CSS Selector for a classname, use:  `.<classname>`

To use a CSS Selector for the style, you can use the [`[attribute="value"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) Selector.

So in your example:

```
[..]

# Using multiple CSS Selectors - separated by a comma.
print(soup.select('.class1, .class2, [style="text-align:left"]'))
```